# Ocultar y Mostrar <div> con Mapa de Google

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

Tengo un `div` en mi página ASP.NET que contiene un Mapa de Google, y necesito mostrarlo y ocultarlo pero no me funciona.

Este es el código *dividido por lengaujes*:

Javascript:

```
function ShowMap()
{
    var mapa = document.getElementById('map');
    mapa.display('block');
}

function HiddenMap()
{
    var mapa = document.getElementById('map');
    mapa.display('none');
}
```

ASP.NET:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="map" style="width:auto; height:390px; top:2%;display:none;"> 
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" Width="114px" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button"  Width="114px" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

C#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ScriptAct = "HiddenMap();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "HiddenMap()", ScriptAct, true);
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ScriptAct = "ShowMap();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowMap()", ScriptAct, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***CODIGO JS***

```
function displayMap() {
              var listCount = $("[id*='hfCount']").val();
              if (listCount == 0)  return; 
              var atext = document.getElementById('btnmap').innerText;
              console.log(atext);
              if (atext == "VIEW ON MAP") {
                  document.getElementById('collapseMap').style.display = "block";
                  document.getElementById("btnmap").innerHTML = "HIDE MAP";
              }
              else {
                  document.getElementById('collapseMap').style.display = "none";
                  document.getElementById("btnmap").innerHTML = "VIEW ON MAP";
              }
      }
```

**CODIGO ASP.NET**

```
 <div id="collapseMap">
    <div id="map">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: acepta esta respuesta si es la que ha dado solución a tu pregunta. Así ayudamos a mantener la buena salud del sitio y con un mayor % de respuestas resueltas podremos salir de la versión beta de SOes. Saludos :D

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el código javascript de la siguiente manera:

```
function ShowMap()
{
    var mapa = document.getElementById('map');
    mapa.style.display('block');
}

function HiddenMap()
{
    var mapa = document.getElementById('map');
    mapa.style.display('none');
}
```

Y en el código ASP.NET, usa la propiedad [OnClientClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx):

Ejemplo:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="ShowMap();" Width="114px" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button"  Width="114px" OnClientClick="HiddenMap();" />
```

Comment: Lo hize Mauricio  e igual...inclusive a cada funcion como ultima linea le agregue un alert y no se ejecuto...cambie el alert a primera linea y si se ejecuto...me imagino que cae en un error ...???

Comment: Puede ser que se produjera un error durante las pruebas. Realiza una nueva prueba, pero con la consola del navegador `F12` abierta.

Comment: TypeError: mapa.display is not a function ,   tambien dice  no se encuentra el elemento

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC, revisa bien mi respuesta, es `mapa.style.display('block');` no `mapa.display('block');`
Nótese el `style.display`. Es raro que no encuentre el div `map`. Realiza la modificación que te indico y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: mapa.style  es Undefined

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC es porque el div `map` no está disponible, antes de llamar a esta línea `mapa.style.display('block');` revisa que la variable `mapa` sea diferente de `undefined`. Ejecuta esta línea en la consola: `document.getElementById('map');` y me cuentas cuál es el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esta línea :

```
document.getElementById('mapa').style.display='block';
```

o para ocultar

```
document.getElementById('mapa').style.display='hidden';
```

Por ejemplo:

Botón Ocultar:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String ScriptAct = "document.getElementById('mapa').style.display='hidden'; alert('Listo');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "hidden", ScriptAct, true);
        }
```

Botón Mostrar:

```
 String ScriptAct = "document.getElementById('mapa').style.display='block'; alert('Listo'); ";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "show", ScriptAct, true);
```